# Merge tab-delimited files horizontally with files of different row lengths

Tags: python, unix, merge, padding, multiple-columns

I am a complete novice in programming, so I apologize for any lack of clarity, extreme confusion, etc. What I am trying to do is merge a large number of files into one file. Each file is tab-delimited with the same number of columns (13), but a different number of rows (~40000). I would like the end product to contain

```
file1col1      file1col2   ...   file1col13    file2col1      file2col2   ...   file2col13    file3col1      ...         etc
```

(where all the spaces are tabs)

The end of the files could be padded any which way, as long as all of my columns are preserved.

What I was trying to do was to simply use the paste command in unix; however, that was not preserving my columns. I tried poaching solutions from a bunch of slightly different questions, but I'm afraid that I'm such a beginner that I didn't even know how to do that. I would prefer to use unix or python to solve this problem, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

P.S. I am doing this with a large number of files (~40), so if the input could take all files in a given directory with the same extension, that would be ideal.

Edit: While `paste -D$'\t' *.b > merge` works for the first section of the file, outputting

```
9       13577718        0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       9       13576563        1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       9       13577772        0       0       1       0       0       0  ...etc across
```

At the end of the file (viewed using tail), everything becomes jumbled and misaligned. I'm not sure how to best represent this and I do not have the reputation to post images.

Comment: what do you mean by "my paste command was not preserving my columns"? Can you show the actual command and a sample of the output?

Comment: Didn't `paste -d$'\t' f1 f2 ... fn` work to you?

Comment: I would start with 41 files, each with 13 columns and a variable number of rows. Then output would have 533 columns and the amount of rows of the longest file.

Comment: What do you expect to happen at the tail of the output? Is it that you want the 12 tabs (separating the 13 columns) generated for each line of each file that no longer has data, as well as the tab that separates those 13 columns from the columns of the next or previous file?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal, or it could be filled with 0's or something, as long as each file has its own data aligned

Comment: OK. I can see a variety of more or less brute force and ignorance ways to do it. They're ugly, though, because they involve scads of temporary files and running `wc -l` on the inputs and finding the longest and then padding the other files with the appropriate number of dummy lines so that `paste` actually does the correct job.  I don't think there's a standard command that does 'generate N lines of output from this file; if you run out of data before generating N lines, pad the output with this dummy line'.

Comment: I didn't notice the Python tag until I saw the answer, so I was thinking in terms of shell scripts. I was trying to avoid writing it in C (which would be easy with the right library support, but that's non-standard so not good for SO). Perl is an alternative to Python, but Python is fine too. The Python script looks reasonable to me, at least once it is debugged.  It should get you a long way down the road, though you'll need to change the string `"None"` into something with a dozen or so tabs in it, and worry about the stripping operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your list of filenames is stored in an array called `filenames` (I try not to be imaginative when naming variables). If the names were given on the command line you could create this simply as

```
filenames = sys.argv[1:]
```

One way to do what you are asking is as follows.

```
output = open("yourfile.txt", "w")
files = []
for filename in filenames:
    files.append(open(filename, "r"))
num_files = len(files)
num_empty = 0
while True:
    num_empty = 0
    line = []
    for file in files:
        item = file.readline() # returns empty string after EOF
        if not item: 
            item = "None" # or other marker value
            num_empty += 1
        line.append(item)
    if num_empty == num_files:
        break
    output.write("\t".join([x.strip() for x in line]))
    output.write("\n")
for file in files:
    file.close()
output.close()
```

The `.strip()` method calls remove any extraneous whitespace, including the newline that appears at the end of a text line read by Python as standard. The `.join()` method takes the elements of the list of strings an concatenates them with separating tabs.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution! One problem that I'm having is that I'm getting the error   `File "merger.py", line 6, in <module>
    files.append(open(file, "r"))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found` and I'm afraid that I'm so clueless that I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug in my code - the argument to `open()` should be a filename, not an already-open file.

Comment: Another editor was kind enough to fix an egregious error in the first `output.write()` call

Comment: The code is executing beautifully now, thank you very much for all of your help!